# Child div displaying above parent

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

Here's my working jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/wNUyk/

this is the html

```
<div class="productslist">
    <div class="products" id="1">

    </div>
    <div class="productinfo" id="1">
        <div class="productdesc" id="1"></div>
        <div class="productimg" id="1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.productslist{
position: relative;
-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 9px rgba(0,0,0,.44);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 9px rgba(0,0,0,.44);
box-shadow:         inset 0 0 9px rgba(0,0,0,.44);
background: gray;
z-index: 1;
}
.productinfo{
position: relative;
width: 790px;
background-color: rgb(202,114,24);
display: block;
z-index: -1;
}
```

I need the productinfo div to display inside the productlist div, in other words, I need the inset shadow to show above the productinfo.

I moved the z-index up and down on both elements with no success.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI: `z-index` only applies to positioned elements, not to elements in the normal layout flow.

Comment: You can only use the same `id` once per page.

Comment: Semantically speaking, @kingdamian42 is correct.

Comment: Not sure if anyone was interested in something other than the semantics, but I managed to solve this adding shadows to the children elements. Not the most elegant solution, so if anyone knows another way, it would still help me a lot.
Updated the jsfiddle already

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wNUyk/6/